# What are the tasks assigned to you in TaskMaker?

Tags: taskmaker

In the classic Mac Game TaskMaker you are assigned 10 tasks by the TaskMaker, if I remember correctly. I can't remember what the tasks were, and I can only find reference to the final task you are given.

I completed the game almost 20 years ago, but I no longer have a Mac that will run it so go back and check.

Better yet, if someone can point me in the direction of a walk through so I can relive it vicariously that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tasks given to the player in the original TaskMaker:

(spoiler alert)

1. Visit TaskMaker in Castle Hall
2. Retrieve a package from Skysail Village
3. Retrieve a chess board from Quietwater
4. Retrieve the TaskMaker's sterling chalice from Silver Creek
5. Retrieve the magic book from the graveyard of Arbalest Catacombs (bring a shovel)
6. Retrieve TaskMaker's belongings from Poet's Nightmare (within Quagmire Estates)
7. Steal the coat of arms from the Enitsirhc family in Enitsirhc
8. Obtain the head of the lead rebel in Dripstone (within Fierce Fold)
9. From Pentamerous, retrieve the King's Bones
10. Retrieve the crown from Vidair's Tower (accessible by taking a ship out of Quagmire)
11. Kill the evil prisoner held in the Island Prison (at least that's what you're told...)
12. Finally, if you choose to:

> kill the TaskMaker!

I have no walkthrough to offer but you can find lots of helpful hints and cheats at [The Unofficial TaskMaker home page (via archive.org)](http://web.archive.org/web/20030515000000*/http://www.btinternet.com/~G.Janacek/Taskmaker.html).  Also keep an eye on the [TaskMaker Wikia](http://taskmaker.wikia.com/) that is just getting started.

You can always play the game with an emulator like Basilisk II, a ROM image ("if you own a Mac") and a free copy of System 7.0 from Apple.  (Google 'system 7.0 download'; apparently I'm disreputable and can't post links. ;)

Comment: I put the spoiler in a spoiler block, I'm not sure how to maintain the ordered list with it in the block though...

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! It's been. A good couple of decades since I played task maker and my memory was about fuzzy.

Comment: I just discovered there is a giant TVTropes entry for TaskMaker. This should stir up some memories: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/TaskMaker?from=Main.TaskMaker